# Can,t print anything when i use print statement in a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a issue with flutter that when i try to print a statement from a function it doesn't print into the console but when I use print statement in build it gets printed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    try {
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
      print(position.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: you are requesting permission, but no condition to check permission.

Answer (score 1):

I can able to get the location properly.

```
void getLocation() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
  print(position);
}
```

Hope you added the required permission in manifest / plist file

Comment: The problem is not about getting the location . I get the position but when I try to print it in console it just doesn't print anything

Comment: are you using release mode and iOS?

Comment: No ios only android

Comment: does print statement work before fetching location?

Comment: when I use print statement in a function it doesn't work whereas when I use print in build method it works

Comment: are you getting empty line or nothing?

Comment: I am getting Nothing